# How do you enable validations after ignoring them

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I'm using the summernote WYSIWYG editor, and it has annoying bug where js throw an error when you click the buttons in the menu.  The only fix I could find for it, which was on their site, was to ignore validations on the fields.  like this:

```js
function summerNoteBugFix() {
  $('form').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('validator'))
      $(this).data('validator').settings.ignore = ".note-editor *";
  });
}
```

My question is how do you enable the ignored fields.